How to implement Traffic Light in a Veins scenario
How can I implement traffic lights in Veins. I tried looking at the veins_testsims example but I don't understand how to allow exchanging messages with vehicles. I would like traffic lights to be able to exchange messages with vehicles on the network.
I tried to work on veins_testsims but without being able to establish communication between vehicles and traffic lights.

Veins contains example code for traffic lights. The code is located in traci/trafficLight folder. The .ned file is located in the nodes folder.
You then need to configure the traffic light in the omnepp.ini file like this:
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.x = 0
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.y = 0
*.trafficLight[*].mobility.z = 3

*.trafficLight[*].applType = "org.car2x.veins.modules.application.traci.TraCITrafficLightProgram"
*.trafficLight[*].logicType = "org.car2x.veins.modules.world.traci.trafficLight.logics.TraCITrafficLightSimpleLogicagationLogic"


if I try I get this error: Submodule appl: No module type named 'org.car2x.veins.subprojects.veins_testsims.traci.TraCITrafficLightApp' found that implements module interface org.car2x.veins.base.modules.ITrafficLightApplLayer (not in the loaded NED files?) -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Scenario.trafficLight[0] (id=37), at t=0s, event #1
and I'm using the standard classes from the veins_testsims example.

Likeliy the files are not contained in 'veins_testsims' and rather in veins
